# Item content not showing on view pager if Item more then one

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I'm using ViewPager with PagerAdapter for images. code is here

PagerAdapter

```
public class MediaPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        private final LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
        private List<String> mediaItems = new ArrayList<>();
        private Context context;

        public MediaPagerAdapter(List<String> mediaItems,
                                    Context context) {
            this.mediaItems = mediaItems;
            this.context = context;
            mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mediaItems != null ? mediaItems.size() : 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
            View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, container, false);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
 Picasso.with(context).load(mediaItems.get(position)).placeholder(R.drawable
                    .placeholder2).into(imageView);
            container.addView(view);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            View view = (View) object;
            container.removeView(view);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == object;
        }

    }
```

It's loading 2 items successfully in Pager. but when i'm scroll to third item It's getting blank. No content is showing there and when I'm going back, previous items also destroyed.
I research a lot on it but not found  any solution. If anyone also got this type of issue and resolved please put solution here.
Thanks,

**Edit : May,18,2016**

I'm Working on cards using [Swipe-Desk Library](https://github.com/aaronbond/Swipe-Deck) and inside each card inflating ViewPager for photos. code is here

**main xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.daprlabs.cardstack.SwipeFrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:swipedeck="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.daprlabs.cardstack.SwipeDeck
        android:id="@+id/swipe_deck"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="480dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        swipedeck:card_spacing="10dp"
        swipedeck:max_visible="3"
        swipedeck:render_above="true"
        swipedeck:rotation_degrees="15" />

</com.daprlabs.cardstack.SwipeFrameLayout>
```

**SwipeDeckAdapter**

```
public class SwipeDeckAdapter extends BaseArrayAdapter {
    private Context context;

    public SwipeDeckAdapter(List<String> data, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.card_layout, data);
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, int position, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(getLayoutResId(), parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v, listener);
        v.setTag(viewHolder);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(final View view, Context context, String item, int position) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

     list.add("http://i.huffpost.com/gen/1279675/images/o-CAREER-facebook.jpg");
        list.add("http://clickker.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/ambitious.jpg");
        list.add("http://clickker.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/ambitious.jpg");

        MediaPagerAdapter mediaPagerAdapter = new MediaPagerAdapter(list, context);
        viewHolder.viewPager.setAdapter(mediaPagerAdapter);
    }


    public class ViewHolder {
        public ViewPager viewPager;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        }
    }
}
```

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ToolBarActivity
         {

    private SwipeDeckAdapter mAdapter;
    private SwipeDesk cardStack;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        cardStack = (SwipeDesk) findViewById(R.id.swipe_deck);
        testData = new ArrayList<>();
        testData.add("0");
        testData.add("1");
        testData.add("2");
        testData.add("3");
        testData.add("4");
        testData.add("6");
        testData.add("7");

        mAdapter = new SwipeDeckAdapter(testData, this);
        cardStack.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

}
```

and you all know the remaining story that i explained before edit it.

Thanks,

Comment: the ImageView are always *empty*. Where are you assigning them a src/background ?

Comment: i have just edited question please look back once

Comment: Is there some log errors?

Comment: Try this :-container.addView(view, 0);

Comment: @Ram I tried this, Its not working.

Comment: Try to get your inflater from the context and remove the mLayoutInflater, because I guess that your problem is that you declare it as final.

Comment: @MachoProgrammer I tried this, its also not working.

Comment: Could you please show me the Activity/Fragment's code where is the pager adapter initiated?

Comment: Do the page image is loaded after a while when open a blank page, and then when scroll and come back it is blank again ?

Comment: @Omar Hossam Image is never loaded image even after few time wait

Comment: @MachoProgrammer I explained all things in question by edit it. please read above.

Comment: It seems all correct in your code. Could you please show us the activity's code? Thanks

Comment: @ MachoProgrammer There is noting in main activity. only we setting adapter there.